# How to visible spinners in inspect mode of chrome tab input type = number?

Tags: html, input, types, shopify, cart

I add input type = number in the cart page of Shopify. But I need spinners of that type:

[image]

```css
input[type=number]::-webkit-inner-spin-button 
{opacity: 1 !important;}

input[type="number"]{
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    -moz-appearance: none;
}
```

```html
<input id="" class="cart__qty-input" type="number" name="updates[]" value="1" min="0" pattern="[0-9]*">
```

It is work in this question's snippet. But not on my Shopify's Cart page. I add but it does not work.
`input[type=number]::-webkit-inner-spin-button { opacity: 1; }`

Comment: You need to check and make sure, any 3rd party APP or JS code is not modify the code over page load.

Comment: There are other ways to hide elements other than `opacity`; the spinner might be hidden with `display:none` or `visibility:hidden`